# Visio 2003: How to remove blank pages

Tags: printing, microsoft-visio

I have a visio diagram (using the database model diagram) that I'm trying to print.

Originally, it was 5 pages wide, and 5 high.  I've reorganized the diagram so that it's now just 3x3, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the now-blank pages.

Under page setup, the print setup tab, paper is letter size, landscape, and print zoom is set to 100%.

Under the Page Size tab, it's set to "Size to fit drawing contents".

It seems that anything I do to try to eliminate the un-needed blank pages also re-organizes the shapes on the drawing.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this is hold down the Control key and put your mouse over the edge of the "paper" space in Visio.  The grip changes to resize shapes so you can modify the drawing size.

Hope that helps.  It seems there are many different ways to do this in Visio, but it's hard to use the one that sticks when it comes to printing...

Comment: The real problem is that when I print I get 9 pages of information, and 14 blank pages.

Comment: OK, just got a chance to try this, and it worked!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I just had what sounds like a similar problem...  turned out it was some of my text boxes (within shapes) that were going over the page (even through the text itself didn't go over)

Was just a case of F2-ing each text box to see which box had gone of the page

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, pressing CTRL-A showed there was some kind of invisible box outside my drawing.  I could click on it but it wouldn't let me delete it.  When you hovered over it, it would show the arrows and let you make boxes off each side.  So I created a box on each side, selected all 5 boxes and pressed delete and it finally went away.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Select all' to reveal any hidden text boxes etc that are on the extra 'blank' page so you can then select and delete

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out (I'm using Vision 2010, but I'm sure this works with all versions)

Click Ctrl A to select the entire drawing. Look at anything that lies outside the page boundaries. Even if your drawing appears to be on one page, the "outlines" may not be. Shrink the drawing until EVERYTHING is on the same page. Voila.

Answer (score 0):

I had a footer, with a page #, and this may have contributed to my problem.  This is what I finally had to do:  (Visio 2007)

To delete second page of a Visio chart:

1. Open document in Word.  Click on symbol for paragraph marks.
2. At top of blank second page, highlight and delete paragraph marks and arrows.  One paragraph symbol will remain on left.  Save.
3. Double click so that you go into Visio program.
4. Click “View” and “Open in Visio.”
5. Click “File,” then “Page Setup.”
6. Choose “Print Setup,” change to legal if necessary.
7. Choose “Fit to 1 sheet across, 1 sheet down.”  Click “Apply.”
8. Go to “Page Size” tab, change to “Size to Fit Drawing Contents.”
9. Click “OK,” then save it.
10. It should take you back to the Word document to check it.  There should be just one page now.  You can move the right margin a little at a time if you need to, without creating a second page.  Hit Save again.

Answer (score 0):

In Visio 2013 I had a similar problem where and blank second page would not go away. Eventually I realized that there is a "Page" area at the bottom (like worksheets in excel), and I could delete "Page-2" there.

In my case, I believe it would not automatically go away because for some reason it was still in portrait mode, while the primary page was landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing an office layout for conference rooms. Extra pages kept appearing and I couldn't figure out why.

Turns out some the the shapes like "Couch" add a page. SO frustrating. Microsoft has RUINED visio...

Comment: It *seems* like this post doesn't *really* answer the question, unless you clarify the answer and remove ranting. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1133767)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem on Visio 2013 Pro recently.  I needed to copypaste a Visio flowchart into Word.  I noticed an extra space below and I was unable to get rid of it.  No answers from here helped.

I discovered that the problem relates to extra large Edit Text boxes attached to Connectors.  These boxes appear once you right-click the context menu of a connector then select “Edit Text” and then enter a text there.

This is what you need to do:

1. Move all the text attached to Connectors to separate Labels, Rectangles etc.
2. Replace all the Connectors affected with brand new ones.

I got rid if this problem when I replaced the straight vertical connector from the opaque Rectangle down to the green IDEF0 Activity box – please see the Word screenshot below (left = before, right = after):

[image]

I wish it will help you.  Long live the ... Visio!