# Remove unused areas of the page in Microsoft Visio diagram

Tags: microsoft-visio

How do I effectively remove all the unnecessary spaces on MS Visio?

Related: [Visio 2003: How to remove blank pages](https://superuser.com/questions/194106/visio-2003-how-to-remove-blank-pages)

Comment: I think this question is badly worded, "blank spaces" in English refers to space characters in text, not unused areas of the drawing area, which is what I think you mean.

Comment: @PaulHerber, you can change the title as long as it fits the problem. It's been discussed here http://help.lockergnome.com/office2/Removing-Blank-space-Visio-drawing--ftopict503670.html with the title `removing blank space from visio drawing`.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove it by changing the size from **`Letter 8.5" × 11"`**,
which is the default value, to **`Fit to Drawing`**, in the “Design” tab.

[image]

Comment: This feature doesn't work properly for me, 3 of the borders are tight to my drawing, and 1 leaves a large empty space. I checked with Ctrl+A to select all and there aren't any objects in the space. It also leaves a dashed line on the right side, which seems to be a print border.

Answer (score 1):

By holding Shift + dragging the edge of the canvas you can change the size of the canvas.

Comment: For me it was Ctrl+dragging, not shift.